# ignore path in pylint config raises regex error

Tags: python, pylint, pylintrc

I have the pylint config:

```
[MAIN]
load-plugins=pylint_django
django-settings-module=kernel.settings
ignore-paths=^kernel/**$ , ^migrations/*$
```

But whenever i want to run i get this error for kernel regex:

```
re.error: multiple repeat at position 10
```

How to make it so it ignores all subdirs and files inside kernel?

Comment: Can you try - `ignore-paths=^kernel/.*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an `re.error`. Which means your regular expression syntax is incorrect.

so to ignore ALL subdirs and files inside the kernel. simply assign `kernel/.*` regex value to ignore-paths so it will look like this.

```js
[MAIN]
load-plugins=pylint_django
django-settings-module=kernel.settings
ignore-paths=^kernel/.*
```

hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Just for Information - by removing `^(caret)` symbol in the beginning -This pattern matches any part of the path that contains "kernel/" rather than just paths that start with "kernel/". `subdirectory/kernel/file.py` or `another_directory/kernel/another_file.py`

Comment: Correct! thanks for adding this info.

Answer (score 1):

```
ignore-paths=^kernel/.*$
```

Change the `ignore-path` kernel value as above.

`^kernel/.*$` should match anything within the "kernel" directory and its subdirectories.

Comment: ye worked tnx, the problem is with my vscode settings